# How to use Where-Object and StartsWith to filter out files based on contents - Powershell v4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to work through SQL files in a folder, renaming them and if the file contents starts with '/**' then I want to remove the first three lines from the file contents and overwrite the file.

The code below works but when adding one of the commented out lines it returns error messages.

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
  $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
  Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$sqlfolder = Get-ScriptDirectory

$files = Get-ChildItem $sqlfolder\* -Include *.sql

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Output $file.name
    $newName = $file.name.Substring($file.name.LastIndexOf(" ")+1)
    Rename-Item $file -NewName $newName
    get-content $file |
    ##Where-Object {$_.StartsWith("/**")} |
    ##Where-Object {$_ -Like "/**"} |
        select -Skip 3 |
        set-content "$file-temp"
    move "$file-temp" $file -Force
}
```

I'm wanting one of the commented out lines to ensure that the first three lines will only be removed from files starting with the string '/**'.

Error message:

```
move : Cannot find path ...-temp' because it does not exist.
... ObjectNotFound ... PathNotFound ...
```

Comment: `if the file contents starts with '/**'` but your code says `filter only the lines which start with `/**` then skip three of those comment lines` which leaves .. no lines being fed to `set-content`. You need to write the `if` in code.

Comment: You rename it Rename-Item $file -NewName $newName 
so you need to user get-content  $newName

Comment: Write an IF condition in that as suggested by @TessellatingHeckler and keep an else condition where it the condition is not met. That should solve your issue.

Comment: It's doubtful this is PowerShell 1.0. PowerShell 2.0 came built-in on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks, I've updated the question and tag accordingly.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler are you able to suggest a solution including the 'if' as I have tried this also with no success. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to only modify files starting with the text '/**' by using an `If` as suggested in the comments. Here is the final code:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
  $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
  Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$sqlfolder = Get-ScriptDirectory

$files = Get-ChildItem $sqlfolder\* -Include *.sql

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Write-Output $file.name
    $newName = $file.name.Substring($file.name.LastIndexOf(" ")+1)
    Rename-Item $file -NewName $newName

    $firstLine = (Get-Content $file)[0] 

    if ($firstLine.StartsWith("/**")){
        Get-Content $file |
        select -Skip 3 |
        set-content "${file}-temp"
        move "${file}-temp" $file -Force
    }
}
```